# Sqoop function '--map-column-hive' being ignored

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import a file into hive as parquet and the --map-column-hive column_name=timestamp is being ignored.  The column 'column_name' is originally of type datetime in sql and it converts it into bigint in parquet.  I want to convert it to timestamp format through sqoop but it is not working.

```
sqoop import \

--table table_name \

--driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \

--connect jdbc:sqlserver://servername \

--username user --password pw \

--map-column-hive column_name=timestamp\

--as-parquetfile \

--hive-import \

--hive-table table_name -m 1
```

When I view the table in hive, it still shows the column with its original datatype.

I tried column_name=string and that did not work either.

I think this may be an issue with converting files to parquet but I am not sure. Does anyone have a solution to fix this?

I get no errors when running the command, it just completes the import as if the command was did not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before hive 1.2 version Timestmap support in ParquetSerde is not avabile. Only binary data type support is available in 1.1.0.

Please check the [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Parquet#Parquet-Hive1.1.0)

Please upgrade your version to 1.2 and after ,it should work.

```
Please check the issue log and release notes below.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6384

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12329345&styleName=Text&projectId=12310843
```

Comment: Its not the format of timestamp that is not working, it is the function --map-column-hive that doesn't work.  As stated above, I tried to change the column to string and nothing happened.

Comment: What is your hive version ?

Comment: It is version 1.1.0

Comment: In 1.1.0 only binary data type support is available , from 1.2  rest of the data types supported added . please check the link below https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Parquet#Parquet-Hive1.1.0 , you may have to upgrade your version to 1.2 and after.

Comment: Okay I will try that. Thanks :)

Comment: if you feel this info is useful , please up vote and accept ,thanks.

Comment: im pretty sure I did?