# sqoop import error for timestamp coulmn in parquet table

Tags: sqoop

I'm getting an error while mapping SQL Server table to parquet table. I have made parquet table to match SQL Server table  with corresponding column data type.

But sqoop infer timestamp column as long. which creates a problem in loading data to parquet table. Loading data to parquet seems to be successful but fetching is a problem.

Error Message:

```
hive> select updated_at from bkfs.address_par1;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable
Time taken: 0.146 seconds
```

Comment: Have you tried with `--map-column-hive` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Sqoop parquet import interprets the Date and timestamp Oracle data types as Long. Which is trying to get date in unix epoch format. So, importing can be handled like below,

```
sqoop import \
--connect [connection string] \
--username [username] \
--password [password] \
--query "select to_char(date_col,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mi:SS.SS') as date_col from test_table where \$CONDITIONS" \
--as-parquetfile \
-m 1 \
--delete-target-dir \
--target-dir /sample/dir/path/hive_table
```

Comment: The question mentions "SQL Server" which I assume means Microsoft SQL server ( MSSQL) not Oracle. In MSSQL the timestamp datatype is an alias for rowversion, which is either binary(8) or varbinary(8) if nullable. These are not dates, they are used for change tracking purposes. Although the question is pretty ambiguous as to whether the column is a timestamp or perhaps it's a datetime. If Oracle maps those to long then maybe datetimes from MSSQL do the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at the below question posted already,

{[Sqoop function '--map-column-hive' being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798900/sqoop-function-map-column-hive-being-ignored)}